# Type declarations aren't generated in Typescript 2.0

Tags: typescript

Ever since I upgraded to Typescript 2.0 the tsc compiler isn't generating definition files for my code. Here is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "./dist",
    "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
    "types": [
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "node_modules/@types/**/*.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "src/**/*-spec.ts",
    "index.d.ts",
    "dist/",
    "build/",
    "node_modules/shn-dropdown/**/*.d.ts",
    "node_modules/**/build/"
  ],
  "version": "2.0."
}
```

With TS 1.8.9, my .d.ts files were generated into `dist/src/` and mirrored the file structure of my `src/` directory. As far as I can tell my config file is correct per the [spec](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/tsconfig.json.md) and [CLI documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Compiler%20Options.md)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know what caused this issue. But it didn't occur again after upgrading to TS 2.1.0.